Как сделать движение объекта внутри области? Unity
у меня есть объект и  зона /область в которой он должен двигаться (  box collider на  image ,который является фоном, canvas), мне нужно чтобы объект "слонялся " /двигался автоматически в рамках данной области в случайное место, останавливался , определял новое место и шел дальше. Пробовал через навмеши  делать ( но насколько я понял стандартные работает только с 3d , а у меня 2d). В гугле предлагали плагин расширенный, но он тоже не помог, поэтому подумал, что можно как либо через бокс коллайдер, но как именно не могу догадаться.

Создай коллайдер, сделай его тригером. В OnTriggerExit твоего объекта, отправляй объект в новые координаты.
